# magento invoice pdf remove telephone from sold to address only

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have been searching for 2 days now and i cannot find a simple solution to my problem.

I would like to remove the telephone from the Ship To address only. If I remove from the customer configuration I lose it on both Billing and Shipping.

I am looking at the Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.pdf

Line 363

```
foreach ($billingAddress as $value){
        if ($value !== '') {
            $text = array();
            foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($value, 70, true, true) as $_value) {
                $text[] = $_value;
            }
            foreach ($text as $part) {
                $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($part)), 58, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                $this->y -= 15;
            }
        }
    }
```

There must be a way that you can just exclude telephone.

Comment: did you checked here : system > configuration > sales > Invoice and packing slip design > address

Comment: This is just a the static address for the company. I want to remove the telephone number from the customer ship to address so they can be used for despatch labels. I can remove it from the customer configuration but I still need the telephone number to appear on the Billing address for other purposes.

Comment: try post here once : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions